# Prevent multiple opening of same window in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to restrict the browser not to open a page multiple times. If a page is already opened then same page should not be opened in new tab. This is because I am using a weighing scale exe file which loads wight value to URL `localhost\weight\{value}`. I am getting that value in my blade `addweight.blade.php` and using it as input in form. So every time the exe load it calls `localhost\weight\{value}` and it opens a new tab. It makes user to feel annoyed by opening same page in different tab. Please help me out with this.

Comment: You can use session for this, to set and get request for any particular page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using local storage.

```
Window.onload=function(){

if(localStorage.getItem('tab')===1){

window.close();

}else{

localStorage.setItem("tab",1);
}

}

Window.onbeforeunload=function(){
localStorage.setItem("tab",0);
}
```